# Why am I not able to insert text nodes which only have zero width whitespaces set?

Tags: javascript, html, textnode

I am trying to insert whitespace text nodes using JS but it's simply not working. Is the `innerHtml` property getting ignored for a `TextNode`?

See my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a7ood6cL/2/)

```
insertWhitespace = function() {

  var contentEditable = document.getElementById("txt");
  var element = document.getElementById("annyoing-html");

  var textNodeLeft = document.createTextNode("");
  var textNodeRight = document.createTextNode("");

  textNodeLeft.innerHtml = "&#8203;";  
  textNodeRight.innerHtml = "&#8203;";

  contentEditable.insertBefore(textNodeLeft, element);

  if(element.nextSibling != null) {     
    contentEditable.insertBefore(textNodeRight, element.nextSibling);  
  } else {
    element.appendChild(textNodeRight);
  }
};
```

I actually plan to insert zero whitespace characters but it's not working like this anyway.

How can I insert such text nodes?

Comment: It's a text node - why do you think you should be using an *HTML* related property?

Comment: Let me be more explicit - text nodes _do not have an `innerHTML` property_

Comment: @Alnitak Okay, got it. The browser however doesn't mind and/or tell me that I am writing on a property that doesn't exist.. Also GWT allows to cast the Node to Element which made me thing there is a property ..

Comment: *Any* JS object can have any property added to it without complaint (unless the object is "frozen").   Either way, you should pass the desired string in the `createTextNode()` factory method, in Unicode syntax (`\u200b`)

Comment: @Alnitak Thanks for your help that worked! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text nodes do not have a `.innerHTML` property (nb: note the case)

The simplest solution is to simply specify the right content as Unicode literals when you create the elements:

```
var textNodeLeft = document.createTextNode("\u200b");
var textNodeRight = document.createTextNode("\u200b");
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML entities (`&entity;`-formatted strings) are, shockingly, for HTML.

For JavaScript, you need to use JavaScript escape sequences.

In this case, non-breaking space, which is `\xA0`

However, it is *very* bad practice to chain NBSPs together to artificially create space. You should be using margins, padding, positioning... ANYTHING, so long as it's CSS. Spacing is part of presentation, and presentation is the job of CSS.

For completeness, you can use normal spaces (`"     "`) provided you set the container's CSS to include `white-space: pre-wrap` to make the whitespace significant.

Answer (score 2):

As has been stated before, `&nbsp;` is a *HTML* entity. You are trying to fill a *text* node, not HTML.

Therefore, to fill a "non-breaking whitespace" (`&nbsp;`) into a text node, you can use its unicode character code:

```
var textNode = document.createTextNode("\xA0");
// or
var textNode2 = document.createTextNode("");
textNode2.data = "\xA0";   // or
textNode2.textContent = "\xA0";
```

Comment: I only used `&nbsp;` to immediatelly see an effect - actually I need `&#8203;` which is a zero width whitespace character. But I'll try your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, text nodes don't have the `.innerHTML` property. Only HTMLElements do. 
So, this will work:

```
var textNodeLeft = document.createElement("span");
textNodeLeft.innerHTML = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
```